dynamically updating the states of individual qubits in a composite n-qubit system
Here’s the scenario:
I am working with a 6-qubit composite state, where the first three qubits $( e_1, e_2, e_3 )$ represent electron spin qubits, and the last three $( n_1, n_2, n_3 $) represent nuclear spin qubits. These qubits are grouped by QRX sites such that:

$ e_1 $ and $n_1$ are at one QRX site,
$ e_2 $ and $ n_2 $ at another,
$ e_3 $ and $ n_3 $ at a third.

I have a separate code block that performs a midpoint swap operation to entangle the electron spin qubits at two distinct QRX sites. For instance, after swapping ( e_1 ) and ( e_3 ), I obtain a mixed entangled composite state, represented as a ( 4 $\times$ 4 ) density matrix for ( e_1 ) and ( e_3 ).
Now, I aim to extend this operation to a full circuit implementation to facilitate further state manipulations. Specifically, I want to transfer the state from the electron spin qubits $( e_1, e_2, e_3 $) to their corresponding nuclear spin qubits $( n_1, n_2, n_3 $) while maintaining the structure of the composite state: $ e_1, e_2, e_3, n_1, n_2, n_3 $.
The challenge I face is dynamically updating the composite 6-qubit density matrix after operations like midpoint swaps, without affecting the states of the other qubits. My initial thought was to use the reduced density matrix approach to isolate and update individual states (e.g., $ e_1 $ and $ e_3 $), but this doesn’t seem feasible for mixed states.
Could you advise on how to efficiently update the composite 6-qubit density matrix after operations on subsets of qubits, especially in the context of mixed states?
